# Keyboard stucks in lock screen on my Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung, keyboard, bugs

If I use the keyboard in a texting app or somewhere and the screen locked automatically, keyboard stucks at the lockscreen and it looks really weird.

This is a screenshot of what is happening on my phone. Does anyone know the reason for this? My Device is Samsung Galaxy S5 with Lollipop update.

[image: keyboard is stuck on lock screen]

Answer (score 1):

My buddy had the same problem and the only thing we could do to fix it was to install another keyboard like SwiftKey, Google keyboard, and etc. It seems that its a known issue and will have to wait for Samsung to fix it.

Edit, I know this isn't a -fix- but at least its a workaround to get you through the day, Short of having to reboot the phone.